# C# StackOverflow Exception at Class

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I get System.StackOverflowException error when I want to create Form object from class in Windows Forms project.
In the Form I create the object of the class and in the class I create the object of the Form. Could that be why it's giving this error?
Here are the codes of the form:

```
using MetroFramework.Animation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Transitions;

namespace MitroT
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        TemelIslemler temelislemlerobjesi = new TemelIslemler();
        bool ac =false;
      
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void metroTextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            metroTabControl1.SelectedTab = metroTabPage4;
        }

        private void metroTextBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            temelislemlerobjesi.yuklenmeac();
            if(textBox1.Text== " " && textBox1.Text==null && textBox1.Text==string.Empty)
            {
             
               MessageBox.Show("İleti boş ve/veya algılanamaz.", "LokumT", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
               temelislemlerobjesi.yuklenmekapat();
            }
            else
            {
                string girdi;
                string[] girdidizisi;
                girdi = textBox1.Text;
                string girdiduzenli = girdi.Replace(",", " ");
                girdidizisi=girdiduzenli.Split(' ');
                foreach(string g in girdidizisi)
                {
                    //2.aşama
                    if(ac)
                    {
                        if(g=="Posta")
                        {
                            temelislemlerobjesi.sonuc = g;
                        }
                    }
                    //1.aşama
                    if(g=="aç")
                    {
                        ac = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And here are the codes of the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MitroT
{
    internal class TemelIslemler
    {
        public string sonuc;
        //I got the error here
        Form1 frm1nesnesi = new Form1();

       public void labelduzeni()
        {
            switch (sonuc) 
            {
                case "Posta": frm1nesnesi.label1.Visible = true;frm1nesnesi.label1.Text = "Posta uygulamasını açıyorum";Process.Start("outlookmail://"); break;
            }
        }
        public void yuklenmeac()
        {
            frm1nesnesi.metroProgressSpinner1.Visible = true;
            frm1nesnesi.label8.Visible = true;
        }
        public void yuklenmekapat()
        {
            frm1nesnesi.metroProgressSpinner1.Visible = false;
            frm1nesnesi.label8.Visible = false;
        }

    }
}
```

I wrote a description line for the part where it gave error.

I tried to make a program that does my wants and I was trying it but I couldn't compiled, it gave **System.StackOverflowException**.

Comment: `TemelIslemler temelislemlerobjesi = new TemelIslemler();` in `Form1` and `Form1 frm1nesnesi = new Form1();` in `TemelIslemler`. You cannot do that.

Comment: *"In the Form I create the object of the class and in the class I create the object of the Form. Could that be why it's giving this error?"* - Yes.  So I guess you'd solve the error by... not doing that.  It's not clear why you wanted to do that in the first place.

Comment: @David I know I solved the problem but I need them, why they overlaps? I cant understand.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods Why I can't do that? What can i do instead?

Comment: @salihon: What exactly don't you understand about the underlying problem?  Creating an instance of Class A requires creating an instance of Class B, and creating an instance of Class B requires creating an instance of Class A.  This design makes it impossible to create either one, because they will *infinitely* create each other.

Comment: @David oh, thanks, I couldn't recall Thx so much

Answer (score 3):

Creating a new `Form1` object creates a new `TemelIslemler` object as part of field intialization:

```
TemelIslemler temelislemlerobjesi = new TemelIslemler();
```

Creating a new `TemelIslemler` object does the same for `Form1`:

```
Form1 frm1nesnesi = new Form1();
```

Which in turn creates another TemelIslemler, which creates another Form1, and around and around we go until the stack overflows or you run out of memory.

Instead, you probably want to pass a `Form1` instance to the `TemelIslemler` constructor, so you can save the reference to a field.

```
internal class TemelIslemler
{
    public TemelIslemler(Form1 form)
    {
        frm1nesnesi = form;
    }

    private Form1 frm1nesnesi;

    // ...
```

```
private TemelIslemler temelislemlerobjesi = new TemelIslemler(this);
```

Comment: _or_ you redesign, so that `TemelIslemler` does not need the reference to the Form.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn Thanks so much